# questions about ImageViewer.gwt.xml

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

Our GXT guy is out on jury duty and I'm trying to figure out a problem with our ImageViewer.gwt.xml file in our application.

We have a file in our model called Global.gwt.xml that contains the following:

```
<module>
  <source path=""/>
</module>
```

We do this because we are importing constants defined in our model for use in the UI layer. These constants are in the same package as this xml file. We then point to that XML file in our ImageViewer.gwt.xml file by doing this:

```
<module>
  <inherits name="com.company.app.model.Global"/>
....
```

I'm assuming that since there is no class called global that there's some magic that translates this into some kind of class that rolls up the classes in the same package and makes them available for the front end.

So now I've created a framework library that imports the same classes for all of our GXT applications. I've mimicked this in every way, but when I start it, I get a thread error. When I open a class in the designer it tells me that it can't find com.company.framework.model.Global which is the name of my new XML file that rolls up the constants in that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh! I'm an idiot. I had mispelled the package. Not the one in the inherits, but the actual package name. That sucks, but was at least easy to fix.

Comment: please delete your question, as it's unlikely to help anyone in the future.